# Place Name into Latitude and Longitude

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a new user to Android. I am working on showing the optimum path between two places.In this case the user will enter the source and destination. Is there any way to convert the place name into longitude and latitude. I don't want to store so much of latitude and longitudes in my database and compare each ...Any suggestion would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html can convert name to `Adress` and that has lat + long.

Answer (score 0):

You Required `GeoCode` Class's `getFromLocation()` method for such requirement.

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> adds = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

Now the variable adds contains a list of the Places name you want.